# How to use a for-in-loop to make multiple objects in a CADisplayLink

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, for-in-loop, cadisplaylink

So I am trying to create 10 buttons by using a for in loop and make all those 10 buttons move down using a CADisplayLink. The problem is that my CADisplayLink only moves one of the buttons down and I want it to move all 10 of the buttons. Please Help! Thanks in advance!

```
var button: UIButton!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "handleDisplayLink:")
    displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    for index in 0...10 {

        var xLocation:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(300) + 30)

        button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

        button.frame = CGRectMake(xLocation, 10, 100, 100)
        button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(button)

        }



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func handleDisplayLink(displayLink: CADisplayLink) {

    for index in 0...10 {

        var buttonFrame = button.frame
        buttonFrame.origin.y += 1
        button.frame = buttonFrame
        if button.frame.origin.y >= 500 {
            displayLink.invalidate()
        }
    }
}


func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.alpha = 0
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You've only got a reference to one of the 10 buttons you've created in `viewDidLoad`. Use an array of type button `[UIButton]` to store all 10 and then loop through each of them during your CADisplayLink callback.

Your declaration would be:

```
    var buttons: [UIButton] = Array(count: 10, repeatedValue: UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as! UIButton)
```

And any time you referenced a button in your original code, reference the button at the current index of your `for` loop using the array index operator:

```
buttons[index]
```

An overview of Swift arrays and the standard library reference are here:

- [Swift Language Guide: Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105)
- [Swift Standard Library Reference: Arrays](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH5-SW1)

So the provided code would be:

```
var buttons: [UIButton] = Array(count: 10, repeatedValue: UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as! UIButton)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "handleDisplayLink:")
    displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    for index in 0...10 {

        var xLocation:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(300) + 30)

        buttons[index].frame = CGRectMake(xLocation, 10, 100, 100)
        buttons[index].setTitle("Test Button \(index)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        buttons[index].addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(buttons[index])

        }



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func handleDisplayLink(displayLink: CADisplayLink) {

    for index in 0...10 {

        var buttonFrame = buttons[index].frame
        buttonFrame.origin.y += 1
        buttons[index].frame = buttonFrame
        if buttons[index].frame.origin.y >= 500 {
            displayLink.invalidate()
        }
    }
}


func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.alpha = 0
}
```

Comment: How would I write that?

Comment: Do you have it working? If so, please mark the answer as correct, and if not, I'd be glad to offer further assistance.

Comment: I cant seem to get it, can you show me what the whole thing would look like all together?

Comment: Updated the resulting code and provided links to documentation

Comment: It crashes at         buttons[index] = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

Comment: Sorry about that - forgot to initialize the array. Another way to do it would be to initialize an empty array, then with each iteration of the loop, create a UIButton and configure it as you like, then append it to the buttons array with buttons.append(button).

Comment: Im still so confused, I dont know how to make an arrray of buttons or anything

Comment: I've updated the code to show how to declare and initialize the array of 10 buttons. Have a look at the two links to the Swift language documentation and play around with some of the examples in a Playground to get a feel for how to work with arrays and the other collection types. Arrays are a fundamental programming concept and having a good understanding of them will only benefit your development as a programmer.